# How to use complex arguments for PyTest inside setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, pytest

My setup.py TestCommand looks like this:

```
class PyTest(TestCommand):
    def finalize_options(self):
        TestCommand.finalize_options(self)
        self.test_args = ['-v','-m "not luna"']
        self.test_suite = True

    def run_tests(self):
        #import here, cause outside the eggs aren't loaded
        import pytest
        errno = pytest.main(self.test_args)
        sys.exit(errno)
```

My problem is with the `test.args` line.

My first proof of concept setup of using py.test within setup.py had the following arguments:

```
['-v', '-k DivHour']
```

to only execute tests that have the string `DivHour` in its name, and that one worked all fine when called via `python setup.py test`.

Now I would like to run all the available tests apart from the ones that have been marked with the marker `@pytest.mark.luna`
The marking itself works fine, as confirmed with successful execution when I run the tests with `py.test -v -m "not luna".

However, above syntax is not being picked up with the setup.py machinery, py.test in this case tries to execute the marked tests as well.

I also tried to escape the `"` with a `\` like so:

```
['-v', '-m \"not luna\"']
```

but also to no avail.
Anybody knows how I can make this work?

Comment: I would guess, you need to use something like this: `self.test_args = ['-v', '-m', 'not luna']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass each argument separately:

```
self.test_args = ['-v', '-m', 'not luna']
```